How to change the canvas size of nicematrix
The following use of the package nicematrix cuts of the arrows below the matrix. In most documents (not standalone) this can be solved with a manual \vspace but I wonder how you can adjust the actual canvas size.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-cd, pgfplots} % plots and sketches
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\activation}{\psi}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sigmoid}{sigmoid}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ *{6}{c} }[corners, hvlines]
    \Block{1-6}{All possible parameters}\\
    \Block{1-2}{Efficient} & & \Block{1-4}{Redundant} & & & \\
    Polynomially efficient & ? & \Block{1-3}{General redundant} &&& Activation \\
    & & Deactivation & Bias & Duplication & Symmetry \\
    \CodeAfter
        % \TikzEveryCell{offset=1pt,draw}
        \tikz \node[below=4em of 3-1, align=center,xshift=-1em] (isolated) {isolated crit.\ points\\ (Theorem~\ref{thm: morse function on efficient networks})};
        \tikz \draw[-Stealth] (3-1.south) -- node[fill=white,align=center,text=black!70] {a.s.\\for MSE} (isolated) ;

        \tikz \node[below=6em of 3-2, align=center] (not_poly_efficient) {empty set\\ (Theorem~\ref{thm: characterization of efficient networks})};
        \tikz \draw[-Stealth] (3-2.south) -- node[fill=white,text=black!70] {\(\activation\in \{\substack{\sigmoid\\\tanh}\}\)} (not_poly_efficient);

        \tikz \node[below=3.3em of 4-4.south, align=center] (not_exists) {crit. points do not exist\\(Proposition~\ref{prop: bias red do not exist})};
        \tikz \draw[-Stealth] (4-4.south) -- node[fill=white,align=center,text=black!70] {a.s. for MSE} (not_exists);

        \tikz \node[below=5em of 4-6.south, anchor=north, align=center,text=black!70] (not_isolated) {crit. points never isolated\\(Theorem~\ref{})};
        \tikz \draw[-Stealth] (4-5.south) -- (not_isolated);
        \tikz \draw[-Stealth] (4-6.south) -- node[fill=white,xshift=1em,text=black!70] {\(\activation\in \{\substack{\sigmoid\\\tanh}\}\)} (not_isolated);
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}



The TikZ elements drawn in the \CodeAfter are drawn in an overlapping position. Therefore, there is no direct way to compute a bounding box as you expect. As said by Celdor, the way is to add a \rule by hand.

There is documentation for this package.
However, you could just append a tall invisible element after NiceMatrix environment s.a. \rule.
For instance, in the code below \rule[-3.5cm]{0pt}{0.4pt} seems to uncover all added annotations.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-cd, pgfplots} % plots and sketches
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\activation}{\psi}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sigmoid}{sigmoid}

\begin{document}

% \rule[-3.5cm]{0pt}{1pt}%
\begin{NiceTabular}{ *{6}{c} }[corners, hvlines]
    \Block{1-6}{All possible parameters}\\
    \Block{1-2}{Efficient} & & \Block{1-4}{Redundant} & & & \\
    Polynomially efficient & ? & \Block{1-3}{General redundant} &&& Activation \\
    & & Deactivation & Bias & Duplication & Symmetry \\
    \CodeAfter
        % \TikzEveryCell{offset=1pt,draw}
        \tikz \node[below=4em of 3-1, align=center,xshift=-1em] (isolated) {isolated crit.\ points\\ (Theorem~\ref{thm: morse function on efficient networks})};
        \tikz \draw[-Stealth] (3-1.south) -- node[fill=white,align=center,text=black!70] {a.s.\\for MSE} (isolated) ;

        \tikz \node[below=6em of 3-2, align=center] (not_poly_efficient) {empty set\\ (Theorem~\ref{thm: characterization of efficient networks})};
        \tikz \draw[-Stealth] (3-2.south) -- node[fill=white,text=black!70] {\(\activation\in \{\substack{\sigmoid\\\tanh}\}\)} (not_poly_efficient);

        \tikz \node[below=3.3em of 4-4.south, align=center] (not_exists) {crit. points do not exist\\(Proposition~\ref{prop: bias red do not exist})};
        \tikz \draw[-Stealth] (4-4.south) -- node[fill=white,align=center,text=black!70] {a.s. for MSE} (not_exists);

        \tikz \node[below=5em of 4-6.south, anchor=north, align=center,text=black!70] (not_isolated) {crit. points never isolated\\(Theorem~\ref{})};
        \tikz \draw[-Stealth] (4-5.south) -- (not_isolated);
        \tikz \draw[-Stealth] (4-6.south) -- node[fill=white,xshift=1em,text=black!70] {\(\activation\in \{\substack{\sigmoid\\\tanh}\}\)} (not_isolated);
\end{NiceTabular}\rule[-3.5cm]{0pt}{0.4pt}        % <-- Invisible element
\end{document}



This seems to me like the \vspace hack that works for the document I am using the visualization in

@FelixBenning It's common to use Invisible rules. They are quite powerful and have many applications. You could try to put simple tabular into one tikz node and do the whole thing inside tikzpicture environment. Then space for all annotations you add should be correctly calculated.

In this case, we can use Referencing an other tikzpicture without overlay to add the needed vertical space. Since the not_isolated node extends further to the right than the NiceTabular, I'm using it in trim right.
Luckily, the i of the isolated node is just inside the horizontal bounding box of the NiceTabular. Though, it is much closer to the edge of the page than the not_isolated node since its inner xsep is part of the bounding box.
Code
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-cd, pgfplots} % plots and sketches
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\activation}{\psi}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sigmoid}{sigmoid}

\ExplSyntaxOn\newcommand*\nicematrixname{\__nicematrix_env:-}\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ *{6}{c} }[corners, hvlines]
  \Block{1-6}{All possible parameters}  &   &                                &      &             &            \\
  \Block[borders=right]{1-2}{Efficient} &   & \Block{1-4}{Redundant}         &      &             &            \\
  Polynomially efficient                & ? & \Block{1-3}{General redundant} &      &             & Activation \\
                                        &   & Deactivation                   & Bias & Duplication & Symmetry   \\
\CodeAfter
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  baseline=+0pt, trim left=+0pt, trim right=(\nicematrixname not_isolated.east), overlay=false,
  note along to/.style={to path={
    \expanded{(\tikztostart)edge[path only,line to]node[note along](@){\unexpanded{#1}}(\tikztotarget)}
    -- (@) -- (\tikztotarget)}},
  note along/.style={align=center, text=black!70}, note/.style={align=center},
]
\path[nodes=note]
  node[below=4em of 3-1, xshift=-1em]                 (isolated)
    {isolated crit.\ points\\ (Theorem~\ref{thm: morse function on efficient networks})}
  node[below=6em of 3-2]                    (not_poly_efficient)
    {empty set\\ (Theorem~\ref{thm: characterization of efficient networks})}
  node[below=3.3em of 4-4.south]                    (not_exists)
    {crit. points do not exist\\(Proposition~\ref{prop: bias red do not exist})}
  node[below=5em of 4-6.south, anchor=north] (not_isolated)
    {crit. points never isolated\\(Theorem~\ref{})};

\path[-Stealth, */.style={yshift=+-.2em}]
  (   3-1.south) edge[note along to={a.s.\\for MSE}] (isolated)
  ([*]3-2.south) edge[note along to={\(\activation\in \{\substack{\sigmoid\\\tanh}\}\)}] (not_poly_efficient)
  ([*]4-4.south) edge[note along to={a.s. for MSE}] (not_exists)
  (   4-5.south) edge (not_isolated)
  (   4-6.south) edge[note along to={\(\activation\in \{\substack{\sigmoid\\\tanh}\}\)}] (not_isolated);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}

Output


The linked Q&A has the same problem as the isolated node will have, something that protrudes to the left of the text area will be impossible to counteract with just a TikZ picture after it. Maybe \CodeBefore can be used here to push the table enough to the right. Or even tikzmark.

I suggest to write \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\nicematrixname}{}{nm-\NiceMatrixLastEnv-} instead of \newcommand*\nicematrixname{\__nicematrix_env:-} in order to avoid the use of the private macro \__nicematrix_env: :-)
